# A singular holomorphic foliation of $\mathbb{C}^2$ with a bounded leaf

Tags: complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, foliations, complex-dynamics

Is there a  polynomial vector field on $\mathbb{C}^2$ which possesses a  bounded regular leaf? By bounded, I mean a bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such a bounded leaf can not exist even if we assume that the vector field is analytic and the leaf is merely non-constant.

Indeed, suppose by contradiction that $i:\cal F\to \mathbb C^2$ is a leaf of an analytic vector field $v$ that is bounded subset of $\mathbb C^2$. Since $i(\cal F)$ is bounded, the vector field induces a flow on $\cal F$ that is defined for all time. So $\cal F$ has an action of $\mathbb C$ on it (without fixed points). Hence $\cal F$ is either $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb C^*$ or an elliptic curve. But neither of these Riemman surfaces admits a bounded holomorphic function. I.e. $i$ is constant, contradiction.

**PS.** Maybe it's better to phrase the above in terms of the following claim.

*Statement.* Suppose by contradiction that there is a bounded leaf and $x$ is a point on it. Then there exists a holomorphic map $i:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C^2$ such that $i(\mathbb C)$ is tangent to the vector field, $i(0)=x$ and $i(\frac{\partial}{\partial z})=v$.

This statement holds just because the flow of $v$ is defined on the leaf for all times. And it leads to a contradiction.

Comment: thanks  and +1for your answer. It is possible that the leaf would be a  non Haussdorf Riemann surface. Does your argument  work, in this case? Moreover may you more explain about the reason you assume the action is free?Finaly why those three Riemann surface you mentioned are the only Riemann surface admitting free action of C?

Comment: Ali, I added a slightly modified version of the argument that should be convincing, here the question of Hausdorfness doesn't appear.

Comment: thank you for this new version. So i understand  from your answer that the Liouville theorem implies such a leaf does not exist. To be honest, befor your answer, i had no idea of maximal domain of solution in VOMPLEX case.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Of course, a solution to an ODE can run of to infinity in  finite time and this is what happen for "majority" of polynomial vector fields. But if one assumes that it stays in a bounded region (which as we see is impossible), it would exist for all times. This should follow quickly form the fact that a solution always exists for finite time.

Comment: Yes  I  was  aware  of  this  situation  for  the real  case  but  I  was  not  aware of  the  complex  case.  after  your  answer, I realized that the  same  real  argument  works  for  the  complex  case.  BTW,  you  pointed  out that the  situation of " skip to infinity"  occur for "majority" of  algebraic  vector  field. This  remind  me  of  a  theorem  by  Chicone  and  Sotomayor,  an old  paper  in  JDE, who characterize  all  complet  algebraic  vector  field in terms  of  "existence  or  non  existence  of  hyperbolic  sink,  source, or  hyperbolic  saddle. So the  generic  situation.

Comment: hyperbolicity  is compatible to  your phrase "majority of  polynomial  vector  field"

Comment: My apology "They  classified  complete  vector  fields  in terms  of  existence  or  non  existence  of hyperbolic  singularity  (or  partialy  hyperbolic  singularity)  at  equator.  Now  is  it  a  good  idea to  consider the  same  study  for  polynomial  complex vector  field  on  $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: I don't know... My knowledge is limited in this area